# ImageMagick - writeImage output produce 8 bit depth image instead of 24 bit depth image

Tags: php, html, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am really new to this ImageMagick & GhostScript thus, I am confused what I have done wrong.
I am trying to convert the cover page of the PDF to JPG, but some of the writeImage output, produce colored once - 24bit, and most produce mono-coloured - 8bit(Which I don't want).

My code is:

---

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="pdf" name="file" accept=".pdf"/>
        <input type="file" id="imagePDF" style="display:none">
        <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

---

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

    //Save file to directory
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $file_destination = "files/";
    //File properties
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    //Work out the file extension
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array('pdf');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){
        if($file_error === 0){
            if($file_size <= 63000000){
                //File destination relative to upload.php
                $pdfWithPath = $file_destination . $file_name;
                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $pdfWithPath)){
                    echo("File uploaded: <br>");
                    echo $pdfWithPath;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //Create thumbnail and save to directory
    $thumb_name = $file_name . ".jpg";
    $thumb_destination = "pdfThumb/";
    $thumb_path = $thumb_destination . $thumb_name;
    $thumb_first_page = $pdfWithPath . "[0]";

    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->readImage(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $thumb_first_page);
    $image->writeImage(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'pdfThumb/'.$thumb_name);
    $image->destroy();
    echo("Done");
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <!--Display image on screen -->
        <img src="<?php echo $thumb_path; ?>"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

The idea of this code is to upload the pdf and store it into the folder 'files'
Then to create the thumbnail of the PDF file, it will retrieve the PDF from the folder 'files' and produce an image, saving the image to the folder 'pdfThumb'

---

I have 2 outcomes for this writeImage, colored and mono-coloured shown below

[Mono-coloured image produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzWGA.jpg)

[Coloured image produce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGIGK.jpg)

---

I want to make all the images produced by the writeImage output to be all colored.
How should I improve my code?

Comment: Try doing the equivalent of commandline "-type TrueColor"

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson advise would be the first thing to try. `$image->setType(Imagick::IMGTYPE_TRUECOLOR);`

Comment: @emcconville I have tried setType, but it still produces 8 bit depth image.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I have tried, still no positive outcome.

Comment: Indeed, the current version of ImageMagick fails to convert a grayscale JPEG to truecolor when `-type TrueColor` is specified.  However, the `-colorspace CMYK` does write a 24-bit color image (of course containing all-gray pixels).

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson However the PDF itself is already colored. How come it will produce a grayscale image (8bit depth image)?